# ADO.net Data Services [DataWebkey]

Tags: ado.net, service

I am using VS 2008(Professional edition) with SP1.I am new to ADO.NET DataServices.I am watching Mike Taulty videos.

He used [DataWebKey] attribute to specifty the key field and he referred the namespace 
Microsoft.Data.Web. To follow that example I am trying to refer the same assembly,but it is not found in my system.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not the first person to come across this.

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/05/19/10424.aspx

Apparently you should use [`DataServiceKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.common.dataservicekeyattribute.aspx) which is in `System.Data.Services.Common`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that Mike's videos mostly date from mid 2008. ADO.NET Data Services has changed since then, that may be why you're unable to find the right reference.

It think you're better off trying to find some more recent material, preferably from the last 6 months.